# How can I find out how Apache makes certain decisions?

Tags: configuration, apache2

As my Apache configuration gets more and more complex and there are many moving parts, it can be tricky to debug problems. Right now, I have a setup where a certain virtual host setup generates a 301 for `example.com` and a valid result for `www.example.com`.

The 301 is to another virtual host that has nothing to do with `example.com`, but I fail to figure out where this comes from.

Is there a way to tell Apache to show where and how it makes the decisions it makes? I am looking for something along the line of:

- Request for example.com: found in example.com.conf:23, processing .htaccess: rewriting to 301 [www.othersite.com](http://www.othersite.com)

Does this exist (or some other way of debugging the complexity of configfiles, .htaccess files and (PHP-) modules)?

Comment: I don't think there is exactly that - Virtual host matching follows: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/details.html - I always recommend to set [`AllowOverride None`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride) and put all configuration directives in the main httpd.conf (and /or in VirtualHost and other snippets that get included in the main httpd.conf)  rather than complicating the issue with `.htaccess` files. Setting a [CustomLog / LogFormat](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html) that includes a `%v` allows you to narrow down the VirtualHost

Comment: Mod rewrite can be configured to log quite fine grained https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging in the ErrorLog